How can I add a custom attribute to the Entra ID access token?
I'm trying to add custom attributes to my authentication token but I'm running into an issue with adding custom attribute. I've tried the methods suggested in:

Issue to add custom claim "samaccountname" into azure ad
Issue to add custom claim "samaccountname" into azure ad
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/how-to-add-attributes-to-token

but no luck.
I'm using Postman with this API:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenand-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

with payload:
grant_type:password
client_id:****
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
username:****
password:****
client_secret:***

Can anyone help me with this specific issue or suggest an alternative approach?
In token I receive:
***
  "family_name": "**",
  "given_name": "**",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "**",
  "name": "***",
  ***

How can I add employeeId attribute in token? With this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/how-to-add-attributes-to-token] I add in "Single sign-on" > Attributes & Claim > Add new Claim > added name, Source=Attribute, Advanced SAML token in addition check and Save.

Do you want to just get employee id in token? Are you using SAML SSO or normal application

Do you want to just get employee id in token? yes!

Are you using SAML SSO or normal application? That's for keycloak integration

To display employeeid as claim in the access token, check the below:
Use the below PowerShell script to create a policy and to assign to the application:
Connect-AzureAD

$claimsMappingPolicy = [ordered]@{
"ClaimsMappingPolicy" = [ordered]@{
"Version" = 1
"IncludeBasicClaimSet" = $true
"ClaimsSchema" = @(
[ordered]@{
"Source" = "user"
"ID" = "employeeid"
"JwtClaimType" = "employeeid"
}
)
}
}

$appID = "AppID" 
$policyName = "Add employeeid to JWT claims"

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "servicePrincipalNames/any(n: n eq '$appID')"

$existingPolicies = Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId `
| Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "ClaimsMappingPolicy" }
if ($existingPolicies) {
$existingPolicies | Remove-AzureADPolicy
}

$policyDefinition = $claimsMappingPolicy | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 -Compress
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy" -DisplayName $policyName -Definition $policyDefinition

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id



Note that: Custom claims are displayed only when you generate the token for your application, not another app like Microsoft Graph API. Refer this MsDoc

Hence, Expose an API and add scope like below:

Grant API permissions:

Make sure to update Manifest by setting below values:
"acceptMappedClaims": true
AND
"requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2

For sample, I generated access token using Authorization code (as my tenant has MFA enabled can't use ROPC flow):
Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientId
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: api://ClientID/Claims.Read



When I decoded the token, employeeid claim is successfully displayed:

